# Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react' - If you want to resolve "react", use "module:react"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have gone through all the SO questions regarding this issue and so far I haven't been able to fix this problem.

I am following a Pluralsight course on React and the example application is built manually from scratch; that means that each dependency is added manually without the use of any CLI. Since the course is somewhat old I had to spend quite some time upgrading most of babel's packages until I got to this problem when running webpack.

This is the list of dependencies on the package.json

```
     "babel": {
       "presets": [
         "react",
         "env",
         "stage-2"
       ]
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.14.3",
        "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
        "@babel/preset-stage-2": "^7.8.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "ejs": "^3.1.6",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "webpack": "^5.38.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^7.27.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.7.0"
      }
```

And this is the webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './lib/components/app.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: 'defaults' }],
                            '@babel/preset-react'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
};
```

I am running the command "webpack -w".

Most answers in SO talk about correctly configuring the "presets" in the webpack.config.js file. So far I have tried several things with the exact same result:

```
presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: 'defaults' }],
    '@babel/preset-react'
]


presets: [
    '@babel/preset-react'
]                       

presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env', 
    '@babel/preset-react'
]
```

The full error I am getting is as follows:

> ERROR in ./lib/components/app.jsx Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): Error: Cannot find module
> 'babel-preset-react'
>
> - If you want to resolve "react", use "module:react"
> - Did you mean "@babel/react"?
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
>   at resolve (C:\Users\sromero\Documents\Learning\React\advanced-react\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:164:23)
>   at resolveStandardizedName (C:\Users\sromero\Documents\Learning\React\advanced-react\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:111:7)
>   at resolvePreset (C:\Users\sromero\Documents\Learning\React\advanced-react\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:59:10)
>   at loadPreset (C:\Users\sromero\Documents\Learning\React\advanced-react\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:78:20)
>   at loadPreset.next ()
>   at createDescriptor (C:\Users\sromero\Documents\Learning\React\advanced-react\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:187:16)
>   at createDescriptor.next ()
>   at step (C:\Users\sromero\Documents\Learning\React\advanced-react\node_modules\gensync\index.js:261:32)
>   at evaluateAsync (C:\Users\sromero\Documents\Learning\React\advanced-react\node_modules\gensync\index.js:291:5)

And for the sake of completeness, the app.jsx file the error is referring to is this one:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <h2>I am working!</h2>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you remove `@babel/preset-react` from the `webpack.config.js` file's presets section?

Comment: @WillWalsh - The exact same result.

Comment: When you say 'each dependency is added manually without the use of any CLI', what do you mean? Do you have a .babelrc file? Are you sure you've tried with just `presets: [ '@babel/preset-env' ]`? That is not one of the options you show in the post as having tried.

Comment: @WillWalsh - By "manually adding them" I mean that each one is added via "npm install". Just to be extra sure I just tried it again and confirmed that I got the same result with the option you are suggesting.

Comment: Sorry. I can't help further. I find trying to use environment setups verbosely from old tutorials can be fraught with debugging, as packages change so frequently. Unless you use the same package versions as they do, anything could be different. Personally when learning new frameworks/libraries, I set the project up using details from the current documentation, ensure that runs clean, then use the code from the old tutorials without the package parts, adjusting as I need. This usually makes things easier when learning, avoiding the issues that come with package version changes.

Comment: Do you have a `.babelrc` or `babel.config.js` file that might also be referencing `react`? There is nothing wrong with what you've posted so far, so it sounds like there must be some other file coming into play. Could you post the entire error output verbatim?

Comment: @loganfsmyth - There is no .babelrc nor babel.config.js file on my project, the only configuration file besides the webpack one is '.eslintrc.js;. I just added the full error like you requested. Thank you.

Comment: @loganfsmyth - I actually started the tutorial from scratch and I noticed I did not include on the package.json fragment the babel presets I have which is the reason why there is not any babel configuration file. I've included those now as well.

Comment: Ahh perfect, you can delete that whole `babel` object from `package.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `babel` key in your `package.json` is for Babel 6.x and references plugins that you do not have installed, which is why you are getting that error.

`@babel/preset-env` and `@babel/preset-react` will accomplish likely everything you need to worry about, so as long as those are installed and referenced in the Webpack config, you're good to go.